# How does this battery charger from an emergency rechargeable light work?

Tags: integrated-circuit, battery-charging, charger

I opened an emergency rechargeable light and saw the charger circuit which is quite simple: a bridge rectifier and then a big capacitor (I don't know the rating). There is no transformer, but the battery terminal voltage is appx 4.5V, but how does it work? When I measured the output of the rectifier I got nearly 270VDC. In India domestic voltage level is 220-240VAC. How is it possible to get more voltage? How does the battery charge with high voltage?

Comment: Is it a capacitive dropper circuit?

Comment: Post a good quality, cropped photo of the PCB.

Comment: Such battery chargers are common in Pakistan too and I have made a few of them myself. So see my answer below for explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the AC mains voltage is rated with RMS value. So in India, it is 220 Vrms. When you rectify it and smooth it with a capacitor, the DC voltage becomes 312 V because of the following calculations.

Vdc = Vpk = Vrms x sqrt(2) = 220 x sqrt(2) = 312 V

After inefficient conversion and some losses, you measured it at 270 V.

Secondly, the circuit you saw for charging the battery was a very clever application of voltage divider rule and capacitor impedance.

It is similar to the following.

[image: transformer-less battery charger]

The capacitor C1 is the large capacitor you saw. It's value is about 0.68 uF or somewhere near it. At the mains frequency (50 Hz in India) C1 has a reactive impedance Xc1 = 1/(2*pi*f*C1). This Xc1 and the resistance of R1 come in series to form a voltage divider. The diode bridge simultaneously rectifies the AC wave.

The value of Xc1 and R1 is chosen such that with 220Vrms at the input, the 
voltage after the rectification is a little more than the battery voltage, to keep it charging.

C2 smooths out the ripples, but it is omitted sometimes, because the battery does not mind any ripples while charging.

Comment: The basic principle of the circuit is same, although yours might have a few more components for protection and improvements.

Comment: Why are you commenting on your own answer? Edit the answer instead.

Comment: Because it is not as important as the answer. I will not edit the answer to add unnecessary details.

Comment: wow, that's a terrible design. no isolation, no regulation, no battery protection, no nuthing.

Comment: @dandavis, it's not so bad a design as it may looks. Remember the ultimate design principle, "If it looks stupid but works, it ain't stupid." Also remember that the schematic I gave was just a representative of concept, not the actual circuit. Emergency lights with these circuits work quite fine for a couple of years.

Comment: My life is worth more to me than a transformer costs. Emergency lights around here last 20+ years, so even if they cost 5X as much, they are still cheaper to replace and maintain, and they won't kill anyone who bumps their head into them or zap kids who take them apart. those factors makes doing it the right way (isolation, grounding, etc) a no-brainer.

Comment: @dandavis we can always argue over what is good for you and what is good for me. but that's not the point here.